# How to check nullity in typescript using Bracket notation

Tags: typescript, object, null

I want to check if an array inside an object exists, is not null and is not empty

I need to reference that property in bracket notation.

My object

```js
profile = {
    myArray: [1,2,3]
}
```

And I am checking it like this

```js
const section = "myArray";
if(section in profile && profile[section] && profile[section].length ) { // do something}
```

I expect this to work but I get an error in this part `profile[section].length` that says `object is possibly null or undefined`

If I do it using dot notation it works right

```
if('myArray' in profile && profile.myArray && profile.myArray.length ) { // do something}
```

Comment: Typo? `myArray = [1,2,3]` the = should be a colon.

Comment: @evayly yes, it was a typo, thanks

Comment: In TypeScript, whenever you use `object[...]` notation, it relies on `object`'s index signature. Because of that, it can't tell that the property you've checked for truthiness is the same property you're accessing the `length` property of.

Answer (score 10):

use optional chaining like so

```
if (profile?.[section]?.length) { // do something }
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58780897

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28081) whose [fix](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31478) exists but might not make it into the language due to possible performance issues.

What can we do while we wait?  Well, one possible workaround is to introduce a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) function which performs the same check internally but forces the compiler to narrow the type of your object the way you were hoping:

```
function hasDefinedProp<T, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  k: K
): obj is T & Required<Pick<T, K>> {
  return !!obj[k];
}
```

The type `T & Required<Pick<T, K>>` means that it's the same type as `T`, except that the `K`-keyed property is required and therefore not nullable/undefined.  Let's see it in action:

```
if (
  section in profile &&
  hasDefinedProp(profile, section) &&
  profile[section].length // okay now
) {
  // do something
}
```

Looks good!  Hope that helps; good luck.

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPY2AGxQbwChlkBbATwEEoo5yB+ALmRAFdSAjaAbQF0BuQgF9ChBBhABnMMgAOmbHmbosuFAF5kREhWq1yzbgEYANMgBMZgMy9hgsROnJJEBGGATkmgES6adb3sYVhA3DxBkAAs4SQARCGwQCAATFVkAHgAVMwBpZAgAD0gQZMlkAGsIcixkTIA+AApiZAwOACtmbOby5hzCAEpmVrbkYDLM5AAyZAAlCABHVmAoFPTUYARyrNy6uq1mlbBWKAiAQlPh7nKBYVFgGGQmkhcwz1A5BTUpyebouITQCk0g15Ko8GYXu4JP1vs1QYoINxIeFeAA6PAgADmYEiyAA9HiWuU6CwMAB3Ab7EgE5DJDDODCkCA40CY25AA)