# Using optional chaining operator for object property access

Tags: javascript, typescript, optional-chaining

TypeScript 3.7 now supports the [optional chaining operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining). Hence, you can write code such as:

```
const value = a?.b?.c;
```

I.e., you can use this operator to access properties of an object, where the object itself may be `null` or `undefined`. Now what I would like to do is basically the same, but the property names are dynamic:

```
const value = a?[b]?.c;
```

However, there I get a syntax error:

> error TS1005: ':' expected.

What am I doing wrong here? Is this even possible?

The [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining#syntax) seems to imply that this is not possible (but maybe I get the syntax examples wrong).

Comment: You miss the point, the operator is `?.`

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks a lot 

Comment: My aside comment: Typescript embraced a previous ES specification, hence I'd link MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 301, accepted):

When accessing a property using bracket notation and optional chaining, you need to use a dot in addition to the brackets:

```
const value = a?.[b]?.c;
```

This is the syntax that was adopted by the [TC39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining), because otherwise it's hard for the parser to figure out if this `?` is part of a ternary expression or part of optional chaining.

The way I think about it: the symbol for optional chaining isn't `?`, it's `?.`. If you're doing optional chaining, you'll always be using both characters.

Comment: I’d replace _hard_ with _impossible_.

Comment: @vol7ron why so - i think it can look forward for `:`

Comment: It wouldn’t be able to distinguish, especially when there are errors.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions Won't happen. There are already a few places in the language where this forward-looking would solve problems. Just think how the statement `function(){};` or `{a: 1}.a;` are both a syntax error. Also: Nested ternaries are already hard to parse (what does `a?[...b][1]?c:d?.e:f` mean). Better not make it more difficult by overloading `?`.

Comment: Wow, that is super-unintuitive since the optional chaining syntax minus the "optional" part is invalid.  You can't run chaining as `a.[b].c`, so `a?.[b]?.c` is only going to be discovered by those who run into the issue and search online.  Maybe a proposal could be made to enable `a.[b].c` chaining syntax?

Answer (score 24):

#### The Optional Chaining operator is `?.`

Here are some examples for nullable property and function handling.

```
const example = {a: ["first", {b:3}, false]}

// Properties
example?.a  // ["first", {b:3}, false]
example?.b  // undefined

// Dynamic properties ?.[]
example?.a?.[0]     // "first"
example?.a?.[1]?.a  // undefined
example?.a?.[1]?.b  // 3

// Functions ?.()
null?.()                // undefined
validFunction?.()       // result
(() => {return 1})?.()  // 1
```

#### Bonus: Default values

`??` (Nullish Coalescing) can be used to set a default value if undefined or null.

```
const notNull = possiblyNull ?? defaultValue
const alsoNotNull = a?.b?.c ?? possiblyNullFallback ?? defaultValue
```

Comment: Is there a difference in doing `a?.b?.c ?? default` vs `a?.b?.c || default`?

Comment: `||` checks for all falsey values, so `''`, `0` and `false` will go to the default, whereas `??` will only default for `null` and `undefined`

Comment: That's the Nullish coalescing operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator