# angular bind data on html with data coming from backend with dot( ' . ')

Tags: angular

HTML -

```
<mat-cell fxFlex="15%" *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element?.appointment }} {{ element?.appointment }} </mat-cell>
    <mat-cell fxFlex="15%" *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element?.gardener.first_name }} {{ element?.gardener.last_name }} </mat-cell>
```

Data from backend -

```
0: {
appointment: 100
gardener.first_name: "dfr"
gardener.last_name: "cvg"
}
```

Here I am having issue with first_name and last_name.
Appointment is coming on my html part fine.
But for first_name and last_name I do not have any clue why this is happening but no data is shown even if I console the values.
Can someone please help?

Comment: @HereticMonkey It is showing error. "Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined".    
{{ element?.gardener['first_name']}}

Comment: As it says in the answers, you need to put brackets and quotes around the entire key with the special characters, so `element?.['gardener.first_name']`

Comment: @HereticMonkey For this it is showing this error - Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword –

Comment: Then you are using an outdated version of Angular or TypeScript or browser. That is the appropriate syntax for [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Optional_chaining_with_expressions) See also [Using optional chaining operator for object property access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58780817/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
{{ element['gardener.first_name'] }}
```

Comment: For this it is showing this error - 
Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword

Comment: If you see a comment starting with "Does this answer your question?" followed by a link, please follow the link and decide if its answers answer the current question. If so, please do not answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, remove dot before `[`