# Optional chaining in node v12.13.1

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having an issue understanding why [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) does not work in my code here. I am sure it is my code that is broken, but I would like to learn what the appropriate way to handle this is. In an ideal world, I can do this:

```
let traitType = trait['trait_type'];
let traitValue = trait['value'];    
let configTrait = overrideBids.traitType?.traitValue;
```

Both `traitType` and `traitValue` are of type String objects. I get a syntax error with the example above. Instead, what does work is this more verbose code:

```
  let configTrait = null;
  if (overrideBids[trait['trait_type']]) {
      configTrait = overrideBids[trait['trait_type']][trait['value']];
  }
```

Is there a cleaner way using Optional Chaining or some other modern JavaScript solution to replace the condition I have above to something less verbose?

Comment: When you use dot notation, the property name is literal, not a variable.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, so is the way I have it the least verbose way of going forward with a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using optional chaining operator for object property access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780817/using-optional-chaining-operator-for-object-property-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a variable property name with optional chaining, you have to use square brackets, just like normal dynamic property access.

```
let configTrait = overrideBids[traitType]?.[traitValue];
```