# Typescript: Updating value of an object that has assignable type of 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have seen [this issue](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-type-is-not-assignable-to-type-never#:%7E:text=The%20error%20%22Type%20is%20not,arr%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%20.) explained from Bobby Hadz for arrays of the same type, but I cannot find anythinjg about objects that contain different types.

Here is the error that is produced.
Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Here is the code that causes the TS error.

```
const geometryCopy : geometryTypes  = {... geometryValues}
//Append the new value to the object
if(geometryCopy?.[attributeName]) geometryCopy[attributeName] = newValue
```

attributeName has its type as keyof geometryType.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on how to resolve the issue or any best practices that I am not following.

Edit: I have recreated the error on [this ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOYQPYFsJigTwBV8AHFAbwChkbk4w9gAjAV0gHkQIAuZEFrE2gAaarXqNWkQgHcMvAM6MQqUbToMozNhEIALKBB7ImGDABsIcEJQC+lBwgwglyPdYAmlgOKYcefABhdxUUAF5kAAoJLSkIADk4HF4Aawh8DBg0P1wCYjJhZBYSD3oIADU4cxZjJS0VZAAfPgEhKCaTM0trZABKZF50bFyiUhRkMIA+ZCp1AHo532GA5ErqiAVkYE24ZCUy5AA3KpqtkGQwPRRDRDA6EhIxGicXO6H-AjWazYjZ9XFNNoOFxeABmNT-GgxIG6OS8ADkdVAqHhEMh0Li+kMxjwNSeyHs8zmgQwJHwFyuyAQLCghnA2WWnxOG2Q+JerneIxJZIGDI+ozIExmADpRXyRl8NrZkAsAJLIFIgDAyZDyhA9LBwNIUlBgMZ0EDkqQ687AO4KIxYTaGDwsEDWMD4hYAQQeEBAHh1fAgKuO6wuGC9GCYACsIAhHepgDBIpyAtz8AB+YUAbQxOkSOAAuv04wQE2nAXFMxAs0LiqVIJKnXMAMq4L158nBsMRgNUml081gMr4wxgGnnJsJuxAA).

Comment: You have a syntax error combining **dot notation** and **bracket notation**: `geometryCopy?.[attributeName]`. I cannot reproduce your question, can you reproduce at this [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA5hD2BbCwBOIAq4IGcoF4oBvAQ2DQEYAuKHNASwDsYAaKMtAJhsYFdEARhFQBfAFBiAxvEZ1YCZGhAA1EgBteuGnCQp0WSHkKlyqagCI6qc2w6puUCuKky5OxegDC8MCCjaFPUxsPAJiADpI+V0lVQ1cZ3oAMwAKdyDvXwBtczsKcwBdAEpojxBMkBy8wrDzRggAdzjNcyA)? BTW the blog describe mutating array, but your's are object.

Comment: @Enfieldli - it is valid syntax. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780817/using-optional-chaining-operator-for-object-property-access

Comment: @Enfieldli it's totally valid syntax (optional chaining), it's not an error.

Comment: @Danila Yeah, you got it, I wasn't aware of it

Comment: @Enfieldli I have recreated the issue and added it to the end of the original question.